# Drag and Drop a Widget in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QTreeWidget where I want to move around the items. This works fine with the cities (see example) but not with the buttons.

First Question: What do I need to do to make the buttons moveable like the cities?
Second Question: If I move the cities I get a copy, but I want to move the city only (delete from original place)

```
class Example(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setWindowTitle('Drag and Drop Button')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 550, 450)

        self.cities = QTreeWidgetItem(self)
        self.cities.setText(0,"Cities")

        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)

        osloItem = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        osloItem.setText(0,"Oslo")
        bergenItem = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        bergenItem.setText(0,"Bergen")
        stavangerItem = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        stavangerItem.setText(0,"Stavanger")

        button1 = QPushButton('Button1',self)
        button2 = QPushButton("Button2",self)
        label = QLabel("dragHandle")

        container = QWidget()
        containerLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        container.setLayout(containerLayout)
        containerLayout.addWidget(label)
        containerLayout.addWidget(button1)
        containerLayout.addWidget(button2)

        b1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        self.setItemWidget(b1,0,container)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Note that you can only ask one question per post. About the move operation, use `self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)` and clear the `ItemIsDropEnabled` flag for all items, for instance: `osloItem.setFlags(osloItem.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)`. The other question is a bit tricky, most importantly for conventions: traditionally, buttons accept a mouse press (with the left mouse button) which will show the button as *pressed*, and will allow the user to move the cursor *outside* the button rectangle and eventually release to "cancel" the click. Are you sure you want to override this?

Comment: @musicamente: Move instead of copy works well with `self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)`

I also have changed the structure. Now the Buttons are in a container and I added a handle to be able to move the container. Dragging works, but on the drop I get only a empty tree item. Do I have to reimplement the drag and drop function? Or is there a more easy way?

Answer (score 0):

An important aspect about index widgets (including persistent editors) is that the view takes ***complete*** ownership on the widget, and whenever index is removed for any reason, the widget associated to that widget gets automatically destroyed. This also happens when calling again `setIndexWidget()` with another widget for the same index.

There is absolutely **no** way to prevent that, the destruction is done internally (by calling `deleteLater()`), and reparenting the widget won't change anything.

The only way to "preserve" the widget is to set a "fake" container as the index widget, create a layout for it, and add the *actual* widget to it.

Then, the problem comes when using drag&drop, because item views *always* use serialization of items, even when the `InternalMove` flag is set.

This means that when an item is *moved*, the original index gets removed (and the widget along with it, including widgets for any child item).

The solution, then, is to "capture" the drop operation before it's performed, *reparent* the contents of the container with a similar copy, proceed with the base implementation and then restore the widgets for the new target indexes.

Since we are dealing with tree models, this automatically calls for recursive functions, both for reparenting and restoration.

In the following code I've created an implementation that should be compatible for all standard views (QTreeView, QTableView, QListView) and their higher level widgets. I didn't consider QColumnView, as it's a quite peculiar view and rarely has such requirement.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Handle(QWidget):
    '''
    A custom widget that shows a handle for item dragging whenever
    the editor doesn't support it
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedWidth(self.style().pixelMetric(
            QStyle.PM_ToolBarHandleExtent))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        style = self.style()
        opt.state |= style.State_Horizontal
        style.drawPrimitive(style.PE_IndicatorToolBarHandle, opt, qp)


class Example(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setWindowTitle('Drag and Drop Button')

        self.cities = QTreeWidgetItem(self)
        self.cities.setText(0, 'Cities')

        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)

        osloItem = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        osloItem.setText(0,'Oslo')
        bergenItem = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        bergenItem.setText(0,'Bergen')
        stavangerItem = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        stavangerItem.setText(0, 'Stavanger')

        button1 = QPushButton('Button1', self)
        button2 = QPushButton('Button2', self)
        label = QLabel('dragHandle')

        container = QWidget()
        containerLayout = QGridLayout()
        container.setLayout(containerLayout)
        containerLayout.addWidget(label)
        containerLayout.addWidget(button1, 0, 1)
        containerLayout.addWidget(button2, 0, 2)

        b1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.cities)
        self.setItemWidget(b1, 0, container)

        anotherItem = QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['Whatever'])
        anotherChild = QTreeWidgetItem(anotherItem, ['Another child'])
        grandChild = QTreeWidgetItem(anotherChild, ['a', 'b'])
        self.setItemWidget(grandChild, 1, QPushButton('Whatever'))

        self.expandAll()

        height = self.header().sizeHint().height() + self.frameWidth() * 2
        index = self.model().index(0, 0)
        while index.isValid():
            height += self.rowHeight(index)
            index = self.indexBelow(index)
        self.resize(500, height + 100)

    def setItemWidget(self, item, column, widget, addHandle=False):
        if widget and addHandle or widget.layout() is None:
            container = QWidget()
            layout = QHBoxLayout(container)
            layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            layout.setSpacing(0)
            layout.addWidget(Handle())
            layout.addWidget(widget)
            widget = container
        super().setItemWidget(item, column, widget)

    def createNewContainer(self, index):
        '''
        create a copy of the container and its layout, then reparent all
        child widgets by adding them to the new layout
        '''
        oldWidget = self.indexWidget(index)
        if oldWidget is None:
            return
        oldLayout = oldWidget.layout()
        if oldLayout is None:
            return
        newContainer = oldWidget.__class__()
        newLayout = oldLayout.__class__(newContainer)
        newLayout.setContentsMargins(oldLayout.contentsMargins())
        newLayout.setSpacing(oldLayout.spacing())

        if isinstance(oldLayout, QGridLayout):
            newLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(
                oldLayout.horizontalSpacing())
            newLayout.setVerticalSpacing(
                oldLayout.verticalSpacing())
            for r in range(oldLayout.rowCount()):
                newLayout.setRowStretch(r, 
                    oldLayout.rowStretch(r))
                newLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(r, 
                    oldLayout.rowMinimumHeight(r))
            for c in range(oldLayout.columnCount()):
                newLayout.setColumnStretch(c, 
                    oldLayout.columnStretch(c))
                newLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(c, 
                    oldLayout.columnMinimumWidth(c))

        items = []
        for i in range(oldLayout.count()):
            layoutItem = oldLayout.itemAt(i)
            if not layoutItem:
                continue
            if layoutItem.widget():
                item = layoutItem.widget()
            elif layoutItem.layout():
                item = layoutItem.layout()
            elif layoutItem.spacerItem():
                item = layoutItem.spacerItem()
            if isinstance(oldLayout, QBoxLayout):
                items.append((item, oldLayout.stretch(i), layoutItem.alignment()))
            else:
                items.append((item, ) + oldLayout.getItemPosition(i))
        
        for item, *args in items:
            if isinstance(item, QWidget):
                newLayout.addWidget(item, *args)
            elif isinstance(item, QLayout):
                newLayout.addLayout(item, *args)
            else:
                if isinstance(newLayout, QBoxLayout):
                    newLayout.addSpacerItem(item)
                else:
                    newLayout.addItem(item, *args)
        return newContainer

    def getNewIndexWidgets(self, parent, row):
        '''
        A recursive function that returns a nested list of widgets and those of
        child indexes, by creating new parent containers in the meantime to
        avoid their destruction
        '''
        model = self.model()
        rowItems = []
        for column in range(model.columnCount()):
            index = model.index(row, column, parent)
            childItems = []
            if column == 0:
                for childRow in range(model.rowCount(index)):
                    childItems.append(self.getNewIndexWidgets(index, childRow))
            rowItems.append((
                self.createNewContainer(index), 
                childItems
            ))
        return rowItems

    def restoreIndexWidgets(self, containers, parent, startRow=0, startCol=0):
        '''
        Restore index widgets based on the previously created nested list of
        widgets, based on the new parent and drop row (and column for tables)
        '''
        model = self.model()
        for row, rowItems in enumerate(containers, startRow):
            for column, (widget, childItems) in enumerate(rowItems, startCol):
                index = model.index(row, column, parent)
                if widget:
                    self.setIndexWidget(index, widget)
                self.restoreIndexWidgets(childItems, index)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        '''
        Assume that the selected index is the source of the drag and drop
        operation, then create a nested list of possible index widget that
        are reparented *before* the drop is applied to avoid their destruction
        and then restores them based on the drop index
        '''
        containers = []
        if event.source() == self:
            dropTarget = QPersistentModelIndex(self.indexAt(event.pos()))
            dropPos = self.dropIndicatorPosition()
            selection = self.selectedIndexes()
            if selection and len(set(i.row() for i in selection)) == 1:
                index = selection[0]
                containers.append(
                    self.getNewIndexWidgets(index.parent(), index.row()))

        super().dropEvent(event)

        if containers:
            model = self.model()
            startCol = 0
            if dropPos == self.OnViewport:
                parent = QModelIndex()
                dropRow = model.rowCount() - 1
            else:
                if dropPos == self.OnItem:
                    if isinstance(self, QTreeView):
                        # tree views move items as *children* of the drop
                        # target when the action is *on* an item
                        parent = model.index(
                            dropTarget.row(), dropTarget.column(), 
                            dropTarget.parent())
                        dropRow = model.rowCount(parent) - 1
                    else:
                        # QTableView and QListView use the drop index as target
                        # for the operation, so the parent index is actually
                        # the root index of the view
                        parent = self.rootIndex()
                        dropRow = model.rowCount(dropTarget.parent()) - 1
                        dropRow = dropTarget.row()
                        startCol = dropTarget.column() - index.column()
                else:
                    if isinstance(self, QTreeView):
                        parent = dropTarget.parent()
                    else:
                        parent = self.rootIndex()
                    if dropPos == self.AboveItem:
                        dropRow = dropTarget.row() - 1
                    else:
                        dropRow = dropTarget.row() + 1

            # try to restore the widgets based on the above
            self.restoreIndexWidgets(containers, parent, dropRow, startCol)

            # ensure that all geometries are updated after the drop operation
            self.updateGeometries()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Notes:

- while the above is done for QTreeWidget, it can be easily ported for generic usage of other views; the only difference is the optional override of `setItemWidget` (which would be `setIndexWidget()` for basic views or `setCellWidget()` for QTableWidget, and with the relative argument differences;
- item views (and "item widget views") and models might have different behaviors on drag&drop operations, and depending on their settings (starting with `dragDropMode`); always consider the default behavior of those classes, and also the [`defaultDropAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#defaultDropAction-prop);
- please study all the code above with extreme care: it's a generic example, drag and drop operations are quite complex, and you might need custom behavior; I strongly suggest to patiently and carefully read that code to understand its aspects whenever you need more advanced control over d&d, especially when dealing with tree structures;
- remember that index widgets, while useful, are often problematic; most of the times, using a custom delegate might be a better choice, even for interactive widgets such as buttons or complex widgets; remember that the base source of item views is the model data, including eventual "widgets" (or even editors and their contents);